# purpose of m3u8 file in HTTP live streaming?

Tags: iphone, ipad, http-live-streaming

is m3u8 file a single file maintained in server for live streaming? is MPMoviePlayerController enough for live streaming to show a TV channel? what are the other possibilities? I have verified [the Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question "m3u8" is the file extension used but the Unicode version of an "m3u" file:

> The unicode version of "m3u" is "m3u8", which uses UTF-8 unicode characters.

[m3u on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U)

I don't know enough about file streaming to be able to answer your remaining questions.

Answer (score 1):

The m3u8 file is the playlist for Apple HTTP live (or VoD) streaming.  It contains URLs to the .ts files which normally contain 10 seconds of audio/video each.
You can put the .m3u8 URL into the iPhone's browser and it will play the live stream.
Here's the sample contents of a live stream's .m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10, no desc
media-000001.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
media-000002.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
media-000003.ts
```