# Create m3u8 file from list of ts files

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I want to create 'm3u8' file from the list of ts files. How can I do it?

I did search in google & read documentation of ffmpeg but I didn't find anything.

Comment: already an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274324/560435   if u want to take list of ts files making each entry from that list into a entry in a playlist. note - #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY   separates the list entry's .   review the spec for 'discontinuity'   for more on construction of your own list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear which of the following cases you're asking about, so here's a quick answer for both:

1. If you're starting with a single file that contains your content
   This is the most common case. In general, there are three steps to creating a playable HlS stream from source material.

- for each desired output level (let’s say Bitrate for simplicity),  you need to create a collection of segmented .ts files.
- For each output level you need a playlist manifest (m3u8) that contains the list of segment files making up the content.
- For the whole stream you need a single master manifest (another m3u8) that lists the playlists.

FFMpeg can do all three of these.

2. If you're starting with a collection of .ts files
   If you really are starting with a collection of .ts files, you could either hand-build an m3u8 file as described in the previous answer, or you could write a script to do it.

In either case, there are some considerations for the .ts files:

- If the segment files do not belong to an uninterrupted sequence (as they would if they were transcoded from a single source clip for use in HLS),  you’ll need to insert EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tags between segments that don’t have the same encoding characteristics or that don’t have monotonically increasing PTS (presentation timestamp) values.
- While the segments don't need to all be the same length, the longest one must not exceed the (integer) number of seconds specified in the EXT-X-TARGETDURATION tag.
- "For VOD content, the average segment bit rate MUST be within 10% of the AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH attribute"

When you've built your m3u8 file, it helps to run it through a validator to find any problems.This is a lot easier than scratching your head wondering why an HLS stream plays poorly or inconsistently across players/browsers.

- mediaStreamValidator on macOS is very good https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/about_apple_s_http_live_streaming_tools
- Also consider the online tool at Theo: http://inspectstream.theoplayer.com/

Comment: How to create the m3u8 file as a hand-build while we don't know the duration of each .ts file?

Answer (score 4):

Can be done with a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
file="hls.m3u8"
echo "#EXTM3U" > $file
echo "#EXT-X-VERSION:3" >> $file
echo "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:24" >> $file
echo "#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10" >> $file    
for i in `find *.ts -type f | sort -g`; do
    l=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $i)
    echo "#EXTINF:$l," >> $file
    echo "$i" >> $file
done    
echo "#EXT-X-ENDLIST" >> $file
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) structure. There's a lot of [documentation at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) (IIRC it was invented by Apple and then got adopted widely), e.g. [a draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23) and a [page with example streams](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/).

HLS consists of two levels: a master M3U8 which references other M3U8 which in turn reference the `.ts` files. You can omit the master M3U8 and just provide the "second level".

As a starting point, it [may look something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057182/400056):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10, no desc
media-000001.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
media-000002.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
media-000003.ts
```

The `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` specifies how long each `.ts` file is (they must all be of the same length). It may either be a relative or absolute path.

Comment: thank you.i know hls. i want create playlist(m3u8) from my ts files without recreate them. must manually create and edit m3u8 file or i can using ffmpeg.

Comment: Why not use bash script for creation this file?